# Check if older or newer date than current (by month)

Tags: php, date, if-statement

I want to check if given date (like 2012-12) is older or newer than current date.

I know how to check older month like

```
if(strtotime('2012-12')<strtotime('-1 Months')){
   echo "true"; // got TRUE ... correct!
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

But what about newer ?

```
if(strtotime('2013-02')>strtotime('1 Months')){
   echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false"; // got FALSE ... incorrect !
}
```

I got incorrect result when checking newer date.

Comment: why do you use a time 1 month ago or 1 month later from now if you want to compare to 'now' ?

Comment: can you expand ? @Pankrates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to add the + to your strtotime function.

```
if(strtotime('2013-02')>strtotime('+1 Months')){
   echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

**Update:**
Some things are weird in your question. For example 2013-02 is not a date but a reference to a month. If you want to check if this is the first day of the month use the full date notation: 2012-02-01. If you want to check if the current date into a month check the current month with `date("n")` (returns 1-12); and compare this to the given month, for example:

```
$date = "2012/02/01";

if(date("n", strtotime($date)) != date("n")) {
 echo 'not current month';
}
```

if you want to check if this is not the current date do something like:

```
$date = "2012/02/01";

if(date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date)) != date('d-m-Y')) {
 echo 'not current day';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare a date with the current time to see if its in the past or in the future you could use

```
$date = '2013-02';
$now = time();

if ( strtotime($date) > $now ) {
    echo 'Date is in the future';
} else {
    echo 'Date is in the past';
}
```

Note however that if you supply a date like `$date = '2013-01'` i.e. without a day it will return as in the past, even though we are still in january. Be sure to take a look if this is the behaviour you want

Comment: if given current date , result is "past"

Comment: That is exactly for the reason I mentioned, would you consider today as in the future then? If you do not specify an exact date and time how do you distinguish whether it is in the past or future. If you want a more detailed answer you need to clarify the exact functionality you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

What about comparing the strings? If you can compare directly the strings, using the ISO 8601 format yyyy-mm-dd they're always lexicographically ordered.

2012-01 < 2012-12 < **2013-01** < 2013-02 < 2014-01
(the bold one being the current)

Comment: I will use this trick , but I cant accept you answer. I hope you understand :D